# How to add primary key to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, schema

I'm trying to make an e-commerce website type thing using Rails. So I've made my models for it. My problem is how to make a particular element a primary key?

```
create_table "bookmarks", :primary_key => bk_id force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "bk_name"
  t.string   "size"
  t.string   "brand"
  t.string   "product_id"
  t.integer  "mrp"
  t.text     "colour"
  t.integer  "stock"
  t.integer  "discount"
  t.text     "bk_description"
  t.integer  "bk_id",          primary:true
  t.integer  "cart_unit"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

This is a portion of the schema.rb file. Is the way I've marked bookmark id as the primary key correct? Also, after making these changes, I ran rails db:migrate command and the primary key portion disappears and it becomes like this-

```
create_table "bookmarks",force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "bk_name"
  t.string   "size"
  t.string   "brand"
  t.string   "product_id"
  t.integer  "mrp"
  t.text     "colour"
  t.integer  "stock"
  t.integer  "discount"
  t.text     "bk_description"
  t.integer  "bk_id"
  t.integer  "cart_unit"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

I don't understand why this happened and why those changes I made (I did save the file after editing) just disappeared. Can someone explain this to me? Also, I'd like to mention that I'm learning Ruby on Rails so...please be gentle with me. :P

Comment: Please do not post images, post code as text.

Comment: @mudasobwa done.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there is a colon and then a comma missing in the very top line of your migration: `:primary_key => :bk_id, force: :cascade`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your migration file:

```
create_table :bookmarks, :primary_key => :bk_id do |t|
    ...
    t.integer :bk_id
    ...
end
```

Do not forget to indicate it in your Model too:

```
class Bookmarks < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'bk_id'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it’s Rails4+, you might do:

```
create_table :bookmarks, force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.integer  :bk_id, primary_key: true
  ...
end
```

In Rails3 you just put an additional statement after:

```
create_table "bookmarks", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.integer  "bk_id"
  ...
end
execute "ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD PRIMARY KEY (bk_id);"
```

Comment: I have Rails 5.0.1. The same thing happened as stated in the question. I made the changes, and on running the 'rails db:migrate' command, that portion just disappeared. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Ah, jeez, you are changing _the `db/schema.rb` file_?! Don’t do that, change a migration.

Comment: Migration is what you are writing. `db/schema.rb` is what is generated by Rails and used internally by Rails.

Comment: Good overview over migrations and the schema files. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark

Answer (score 0):

Don't change content of `schema.rb` file. This content will be auto generated from your migrate files. Try find your create bookmarks migrate file and add `:primary_key => bk_id` to it.

File: `db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx_create_bookmarks.rb`
(*`xxxxxxxxx` is a timestamp*)

Help it helps.